# Custom created button on JOptionPane does not work?

Tags: java, swing, button, joptionpane

I have added my own JPanel and JButton to JOptionPane as below.
When I click on the "OK" Button nothing shows up. Is there any alternative to it? i want to just get user's Username and Password but with my button not default from JOptionpane.
Can any body see what is wrong with this code?

```
final WebTextField user = new WebTextField();
    final WebPasswordField password = new WebPasswordField();
    WebButton ok = new WebButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Zip file exist, continuing with extraction of zip file");
                }
            });

        }
    });
    WebButton cancel = new WebButton("Cancel");
    WebPanel panel = new WebPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.add(new WebLabel("User:"));
    panel.add(user);
    panel.add(new WebLabel("Password:"));
    panel.add(password);

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.WHITE);

    int o =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(bcfiDownloadPanel,
            new Object[]{panel},
            "Authorization Required",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            new WebButton[]{new WebButton("OK"), new WebButton("Cancel")}, // this is the array
            "default"
    );
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @itro : is your keyboard working property? You always miss certain characters from your text while typing. Moreover you are initializiing your WebButton twice, one at the start of the code you provided and one inside your showOptionDIalog(); for some reason, do check that. Not sure, but seems like they both refer to the same thing!!   Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unusual JOptionPane though... I do hope that WebButton is something that extends JButton;

```
int o =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(bcfiDownloadPanel,
        new Object[]{panel},
        "Authorization Required",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        new WebButton[]{new WebButton("OK"), new WebButton("Cancel")}, // this is the array
        "default"
```

... so, as for any JButton, you should add action listener to it to make it listent to click event etc;

modify your code in something like this way:

```
int o =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(bcfiDownloadPanel,
            new Object[]{panel},
            "Authorization Required",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            new WebButton[]{this.ok, this.cancel}, // this is the array
            "default"
```

Report that helps

Good luck